# Mongoose Update Parent Document adding existing subdocument id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have Two mongoose models. Category and Subcategory.

These models are auto loaded using the login in meanjs.org.

`category.model.js` as below

```
...

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: {
      unique: true,
      sparse: true
    },
    validate: [validateProperty, 'Please enter Category Name !']
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  subCatagories: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'SubCategory'
    }
  ],
  updated: {
    type: Date
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'active', 'inactive', 'removed'
    ],
    default: 'active'
  }
});

...

mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

And `subcategory.model.js` as below

```
...

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubCategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: {
      unique: true,
      sparse: true // For this to work on a previously indexed field, the index must be dropped & the application restarted.
    },
    validate: [validateProperty, 'Please enter SubCategory Name !']
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: [
      'active', 'inactive', 'removed'
    ],
    default: 'active'
  }
});

...

mongoose.model('SubCategory', SubCategorySchema);
```

Normally Subcategories and Categories will add separately and later I need to assign subcategories to categories.

My category update method as below mentioned code

```
...
categoryRouter.route('/:catId').put((req,res)=>{
 let category = req.category;
   category = _.extend(category, _.pick(req.body, whitelistedFieldsForUpdate));
   category.updated = Date.now();

   category.save(function(err) {
     if (err) {
       return res.status(422).json({message: err});
     }
     res.json(category);
   });
 });
...
```

category create route is as below

```
categoryRouter.route('/').post((req, res) => {
  req.body = _.pick(req.body, whitelistedFieldsForCreate);
  let category = new Category(req.body);
  category.save().then((data) => {
    if (!data) {
      res.status(422).json({message: "An error occured saving Category!"});
    }
    res.status(200).json(data);
  }).catch((err) => {
    res.status(422).json(err);
  })
}));
```

First I POST to my subcategory end point and created Some Subcategories. Then I POST to category and without subcategories and created category objects also. Now I need to PUT (Update) category object with it's subcategory ids to put in it's subcategories array.

When I send a put request with subCategories with object id like `592e9878ee00dd962deb6e2e` of a subcategory which exists in database it does't update.

Comment: A PUT request to where? Which collection are you trying to update? Category or subCategories? Updating should be done on the subCategories if it's a change to that data since it's a referenced collection.

Comment: When I creating category I keep subcategory array empty. the put request code for category is mentioned. When I send a put request to category with subcategory id I need to add that subcategory to category model's subcategories array

Comment: Are we talking about "creating" which should be a POST, or "upating" which should be a "PUT". If you "create" then you save in both collections right? A new entry in subCategory and the `_id` reference in the Category. When you "update" however, you are just talking to subCategory. So the changes are made there, and the `_id` is the same so nothing to change in Category. I'm basically guessing you are trying to access from Category. Which is the wrong way around. Use subCategory for the PUT "update"

Comment: Seems my english is not good. Sorry about that.

First I POST to my subcategory end point and created Some Subcategories. Then I POST to category and without subcategories and created category objects also. Now I need to PUT (Update) category object with it's subcategory ids to put in it's subcategories array. I'm I clear about this

Comment: Show the actual code you are doing this with in your question. My point is that it sounds like you are doing this the wrong way around. We can at least correct your code if you actually post it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145601/discussion-between-user2473015-and-neil-lunn).